# How do you run a function when you click on an image in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

How would you run a function when you click on an image in pygame? In my program, I want to run a specific function when you click on a certain image. The problem is, I have no idea how to do that. Is it even possible to do that? Here is my code below...

```
import pygame


black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
pygame.init()
size = (500, 400)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(150,450,100,50))
button1 = pygame.Rect(100,100,50,50)
button2 = pygame.Rect(200,200,50,50)
button3 = pygame.Rect(130,250,50,50)
pygame.display.set_caption("Yami no Game")

txt = pygame.image.load('txt.png')
Stxt = pygame.transform.scale(txt,(48,48))

exe = pygame.image.load('exe.jpg')
Sexe = pygame.transform.scale(exe,(48,48))

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_image=pygame.image.load('windows_background.jpg').convert()
 
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            100, 100 = event.pos
            if Sexe.get_rect().collidepoint(100,100):
                print('Runnig thing')
    
    screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])
    screen.blit(Stxt,[100,100])
    screen.blit(Sexe,[250,250])

 

    pygame.display.update()
 

    clock.tick(60)
 

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect for a mouseclick then check the position of the mouse when the click occurred and see whether it was within the image by using the collidepoint function:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if Sexe.get_rect().collidepoint(mousePos):
            runFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you speak of using a button to execute something. For this we need to know where the player clicked with the mouse, test if it is inside the area that depicts the image (our "button") and if so, execute a function. Here is a small example:

```
    # get the mouse clicks
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()   # position
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()  # left/right click

    if img.x + img.width > mouse[0] > img.x and img.y + img.height > mouse[1] > img.y:  # Mouse coordinates checking.
         
         if click[0] == 1: # Left click
             my_function_on_click()
```

It requires your image object to have an `x` and a `y` coordinate as well as a defined `height` and `width`. It is a lot easier if your image object has a rect the same size as you can call on that rect, or as the other answer pointed out use the `collidepoint` function.

Minimal example using the code you copied into the comments:

```
width = 48
height = 48
x = 100
y = 100

exe = pygame.image.load('exe.jpg')
Sexe = pygame.transform.scale(exe,(width,height))

 while not done: 
    screen.blit(Sexe,[x,y]) # blit image

    for event in pygame.event.get():        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True 

 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    position click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() # left/right click 

    # Mouse coordinates checking:
    sexe_rect = Sexe.get_rect()
    if sexe_rect.x + sexe_rect.width > mouse[0] > sexe_rect.x and sexe_rect.y + sexe_rect.height > mouse[1] > sexe_rect.y: 
    # if Sexe.get_rect().collidepoint(mousePos): # Alternative, A LOT shorter and more understandable
     
        if click[0] == 1: # Left click 
            print("I GOT CLICKED!")
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to this, is it meant to look like this? Because there is an invalid syntax error

Comment: ```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()   # position
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()  # left/right click
    if Sexe.[100] + Sexe.(48) > mouse[0] > Sexe.[100] and Sexe.[100] + Sexe.(48) > mouse[1] > Sexe.[100]:  # Mouse coordinates checking.
        if click[0] == 1: # Left click
            runFunction()#ignore this

Comment: I edited my post and included both options - checking manually with width/height, or checking with `collidepoint` as the other answer suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however nothing happens when i click on the picture. I also used the `collidepoint` function.

Comment: I don't have python at hand at the moment, but I would suggest printing the mouse coordinates and checking manually with the rect coordinates, width and length to see where the error is.